# Vue, dynamically import template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to be able to swap out a template for a component based on a data property, or a prop. Is this possible?

This is my idea, however this doesn't work of course.

`./index.vue`

```js
export default {
    props:{

    },
    template: import(`./Themes/Templates/${this.template}`),
    data: function() {
        return {
            template: 'Default'
        }
    },
```

`./Themes/Templates/Default.vue`

```html
<div>
    <p>Default template</p>
</div>
```

Currently getting this error:

> invalid template option:[object Module]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `component` that vue.js provide:

```
<template>
  <component :is="myComp"></component>
</template>

...
// You need to import all the possible components
import CompOne from '/CompOne.vue';
import CompTwo from '/CompTwo.vue'

props:{
  myComp: {
    default: 'comp-one',
    type: String,
  },
},
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I did a similar thing to this, however dynamically imported the template.

Comment: How can this be adjusted to apply to dynamic html templates, not importing whole .vue files? I'm trying to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67786214/how-do-you-dynamically-import-a-vue-template-into-a-component

Answer (score 1):

Try `require("./Themes/Templates/Default.vue")`

**Update:**

In `Default.vue`:

```js
...
export default {
    name: "Default"
}
...
```

and in `index.vue`:

```js
...
template: this.temp,
data() {
    const { Default } = import("./Themes/Templates/Default.vue");

    return {
        temp: Default
    }
}
...
```

Comment: This gives me this following error: `invalid template option:[object Module]`