# How do you dynamically import & parse an external HTML template into a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-component, vuejs3, webpack-4

**TL;DR:**

Converting a backbone/jquery app into Vue 3. Have over 400+ html template files for different views. Would like to be able to dynamically parse these these html templates in their original format, without having to do significant rewrite. Also would like to be able to add template references to Vue components in the html and have Vue parse that.

### Original issue

How can you define an external or dynamic HTML template (like `MyVueTemplate.html`) within a Vue component?
Something like (pseudo code):

```
export default {
    name: "MyComponent",
    template: import(`@/views/${this.html_id}.html`),
    props: {
        html_id: String,
    },
    components: {
    }
};
```

Once this works, I need to be able to have temp.html contain tags to Vue Components like `<MyOtherViewComponent variable1="test"></MyOtherViewComponent>` which is then parsed by Vue.

I'm hoping that the webpack import() statement can be used in same way we are currently importing the html templates, but then also parse the Vue component references during build. But if need be, runtime compilation could also be a (less preferred) option.

There are over 400 html files, so currently refactoring them all manually to Vue components wont be feasible, hence this approach. Using Vue 3, but even solutions for Vue 2 would offer a starting point for more research.

Hope someone has some insight on this problem.

---

### Update

So far it looks like the only way to be able to have Vue components within the old html, is to have  tags in the html, and use createApp().mount() to create individual Vue instances for each of those components. Not ideal, but might be the only way.

Comment: I did some searching around.. maybe you can find some ideas here: https://medium.com/scrumpy/dynamic-component-templates-with-vue-js-d9236ab183bb

Comment: @redfox05 could you work with `v-html`?

Comment: @PeterKrebs Thanks but sadly ive already tried that, it works for dynamically loaded components, but I need something where the source file is pure html, as thats the format our 400+ templates are in :(
wittgenstein thanks, but sadly v-html does not work here. `"Note that the contents are inserted as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates."`

Answer (score 0):

You need the [runtime template compiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-runtime-template-compiler) - otherwise, if your templates were Vue components then you could have been able to load them by HTTP as explained in https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/

Comment: Runtime is not ideal, was hoping it could be similar to how webpack does lazy load with dynamic imports yet still compiles this offline during build. But thanks for the input on runtime.

Comment: I have to admit that I am confused - first you say that you **do not** want to compile these as Vue components and now you say that you expect Webpack to somehow `compile` them. This is how Angular works - it fetches HTML templates during runtime, but this is not how Vue works. So I am afraid you will have to look for a different way to achieve your goal.

Comment: by definition templates (not just vue templates) require compilation - be it runtime or build time, compilation is just the process of identifying the "dynamic" part of your template so that it can be rendered. A lot of framework does not call it compilation, but that is just a naming thing.

If you want your html to be processed at build time but loaded lazily at runtime, you need to convert them into single file components and then define them as async components. Wepack will handle these the same way how it handles dynamic imports

Comment: @IVOGELOV I totally understand its hard to follow, its hard to explain too. Webpack's import() function bundles the required files into code later fetched on the fly at runtime. However, it wont parse the html for Vue template code, this is what I was seeking. I'll update the question with a TL;DR to see if that helps.

Comment: @Xinchao yes you've pretty much said what I'm looking to achieve, its hard to explain. Happy for the templates to be compiled during build, and just loaded lazily at runtime, as those are static anyway. But can it be done with the files in .html format, as its unfeasible to convert them all (400+) to vue files. The JS is also totally separated.

Comment: Well, if you do not want to convert HTML to Vue - you can simply use the browser's Fetch API to load the desired HTML file at run-time and then use whatever interpolation engine you like to populate the dynamic parts of your static HTML "templates" - e.g. https://olado.github.io/doT/index.html

Comment: @IVOGELOV but thats using a totally different templating engine, it would not compile vue references in the template. Vue does allow runtime compilation, but so far I have yet to find a way to parse the html for vue component references. So far the only way is to mount each component as a separate vue app programatically targeting the mount point of each app to the relevant div id.

Comment: I really do not understand you ... If you don't want to compile the templates at runtime - then you have to compile them at build time. At build time they can be compiled by Vue template compiler - just like any other single-file Vue component. At runtime they can be compiled by the compiler from the link in my answer. If neither of these 2 works for you - then you're on a dead end street ...