# How to create a vuejs3 or nuxt3 component from data loaded from an API

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component, nuxtjs3, vuejs3-composition-api

I'm creating a SPA on Nuxt 3 (ssr: false) that loads data from a Drupal site.

Each "page" of my SPA corresponds to a Drupal page loaded via Drupal JSON API and I can use the `v-html` directive without problem in my component.

Now I would like to use my html as a real component with reactive data, actions etc. For example interpolating things like `<p>Lorem ipsum {{ foo }}</p>` or `<button @click="bar">Validate</button>`

I saw that maybe there was something to do with the `defineComponent()` or `h()` functions but I can't do it at all.

Is this possible and if so how?
Is there a component or directive that already does this?

Thank you for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67789643/5962802